# How to set default print 'zoom > scale to paper size' to be A4 from c# code?

Tags: c#, winforms, office-automation

I'm using the following code to create a word document from my c# application:

```
oWord = new Word.Application();
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
oDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperLegal;
```

Is there a way I can specify (using c# code) the printing option

```
Zoom > "Scale to paper Size"
```

to be A4 whenever this document is printed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the options when printing the document: in the PrintOut method, specify these values:

```
PrintZoomPaperWidth = 11907
PrintZoomPaperHeight = 16839
```

Comment: Is there no way I can change the zoom setting for the specific document without manually initiating a printout? I just want the zoom setting to be set to A4 whenever the user decides to print it.

Comment: @Themos not by the look of it. You could provide a Print button on the document that calls a macro which sets these values, but that has it's  own problems with macro security etc.